# jquery repeat process once get reply from php file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i have one php file which process adding of record in Database fro array.

for example in array i have 5 items

```
        aray an='abc','xyz','ert','wer','oiu'
```

i want to call one php file in j query ajax method

```
   um = an.split(',');
    var counter = 0;
   if(counter < uemail.length) {
   $("#sending_count").html("Processing Record "+ ecounter +" of " + an.length);
   var data = {uid: um[counter]
   $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
  url: "save.php",
  data: data,
   success: function(html){
   echo "added";
   counter++; 
   }
```

what it do, it complete all the prcess but save.php is still working
what i want after one process it stop untill process of save.php complete then it wait for next 10 sec and start adding of 2nd element.

Thanks

Comment: i know it's not the answer, but there's a `}` missing here: `var data = {uid: um[counter]` and a `})` at the end of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your issue correctly, but you may want to use synchronous (blocking) ajax calls instead of asynchronous (non-blocking). When you make asynchronous call, code execution continues immediately, leaving ajax calls "in the background". Synchronous call blocks the code execution until the request has finished.

```
$.ajax({ async: false, ... });
```

Answer (score 0):

It not my place to question why you would want to do this, although want you are trying could result in a slow and unresponsive UI.

You'll want a `while` loop, not an `if` loop:

```
while(counter < uemail.length) {
```

Other solution that present themselves,

You'll want to turn off the `async` flag to ensure the call is complete, before executing the next line. The `delay()` function will also help.

```
$.ajax({   
    async: false,  //ensure our requests are synchronous.
    type: "POST",   
    url: "save.php",   
    data: data,   
    success: function(html){   
        echo "added";  //?? not a valid javascript function
        delay(10000);  //10000ms = 10 seconds.
    }
    counter++;
```

}

Also,`echo` is not a valid jQuery/javascript function, and your braces are somewhat unclear, and probably misssing.

I have assumed above that `counter++` is outside your loop, because if it wasn't and you got a failure then it could continue forever.